# Different outputs depending on responses to multiple questions (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am trying to get the code to ask the user to choose either k or lambda and then the code needs to ask for a scale parameter for lambda (if k was chosen) or a shape parameter for k (if lambda was chosen). From here, I need the code to ask the user for an input to get min. value, max. value and increments of k (or lambda) depending on what they chose originally.

for example, the output would go:

Would you like to plot curves which vary in: Shape parameter (k) or scale parameter (lambda)?

Please Choose: (user input - k)

Please enter a scale parameter for lambda: (user input - 2)

Please enter the max. value, min. value and increments of k:

maximum k value (>0): (user input - 1)

minimum k value (>min. k value): (user input - 3)

increments of k (between min. and max. value): (user input - 2)

---

This is what I've gotten so far

```
#ask user if they want a fixed value of k or lambda
print("Do you wish to plot curves which vary in:")
print("Shape parameter (k) or scale parameter (lambda)?")
  
    
    
def get_klambda():
    global klambda
    while True:
        try:
            klambda = str(input("Please select "))
            if (klambda =="k"):
                k = input("Please enter a scale parameter for lambda: ")
                if k <=0:
                    break
                raise ValueError()
                except ValueError:
                print("The scale parameter for lambda must be greater than 0!")
            break
                
                
            if (klambda=="lambda"):
                lamda = input("Please enter a shape parameter for k: ")
                if lamda <=0:
                    break
                raise ValueError()
            except ValueError:
                print("The shape parameter for k must be greater than 0!")
            break
raise ValueError()
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter either (k) or (lambda)")          
get_klambda() 

#get min, max and inc of k 
if (klambda == "k"):
    print("Please enter the min. value, max. value and increment for the shape parameter (K) ")
def get_kmin():
    global kmin
    while True:
        try:
            kmin = float(input("Please enter minimum k value: "))
            if kmin >=0.1:
                break
            raise ValueError()
        except ValueError:
            print("The minimum k value must be greater than 0!")
get_kmin()
```

I keep getting syntax error where it says (except ValueError:) after k<=0:..

I am using Python 3
Please help.

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. `except` is not aligned with `try`.

Comment: Remember that `input` always returns a string.  You never need to do `str(input(...))`, but if you really want an integer (like  `k` and `lamda`),  then you must do `int(input(...))`.

Comment: Don't use exceptions like this.  Exceptions are use to communicate with outside functions.  In this case, just use `if` statements.  I'll show an example below.

Comment: Ahh, moving except to try fixed it... I've now another problem where it says "except ValueError:" just above print("Please enter either (k) or (lambda)"..  the error is "Unexpected indent" but regardless of where I move it the error persists

Comment: Thank you so much Tim!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming from your description that you want EITHER k or lambda, so the user doesn't need to specify both.  That would be done like this.  Note that I have removed your raising of exceptions.  When you are doing your own validation, don't use exceptions.  Just use `if` statements.

In this case, removing the exceptions also means you won't catch invalid inputs, like if the user supplies the value "cat" for `k`.  Whether you need to catch that depends on the sophistication of your users.  If they were trying to break your code, well maybe they deserve to see the exception.

```
#ask user if they want a fixed value of k or lambda  
    
def get_klambda():
    print("Do you wish to plot curves which vary in:")
    print("Shape parameter (k) or scale parameter (lambda)?")

    lamda = -1
    k = -1
    while True:
        klambda = input("Please select ")
        if klambda == "k":
            k = int(input("Please enter a scale parameter for lambda: "))
            if k > 0:
                break
            print("The scale parameter for lambda must be greater than 0!")                
        elif klambda == "lambda":
            lamda = int(input("Please enter a shape parameter for k: "))
            if lamda > 0:
                break
            print("The shape parameter for k must be greater than 0!")
        else:
            print("Please enter either (k) or (lambda)")          
    return klambda, k, lamda

klamda, k, lamda = get_klambda()
```